# Как избавиться от повторений условий внутри if

Tags: c++, исключения

У меня есть много разных условий по типу

```
if(...код 0..)
{
  throw WSAException();
}
if(...код 1..)
{
  throw WSAException();
}
if(...код 2..)
{
  throw WSAException();
}
if(...код 3..)
{
  throw WSAException();
}
```

и т.д

как видите `throw WSAException();` постоянно повторяется 
Я бы хотел написать эту функцию один раз для всех условий.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97386/discussion-on-question-by-loli-------if).

Comment: Можете сделать массив функций, которые  реализуют `code 1`, `code 2` ... и проверять их вызывая в цикле `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) if (f[i](...) throw ...;` / Только всерьез подумайте, а нельзя ли обойтись **без исключений**

Comment: @avp вероятно можно обойтись без исключений но пока я не нашел лучшего способа.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пользуемся тем, что если уж сгенерировалось исключение - все остальные `if` не проверяются.

Самое время вспомнить о сокращенном вычислении - в

```
if (a || b || с ...)
```

при первом же истинном выражении все остальные не вычисляются. Так что...

```
if (код1 || код2 || код3 ...) throw...
```

Не понимаю, что вы хотите в точности, но напишите макрос - типа

```
#define THROWIF(x) if (x) { throw 1; }
```

или

```
#define THROWIF(x,y) if (x) { throw y; }
```

**Update**

Если и [это](http://ideone.com/jIfJmO) не убедит - тогда уж не знаю совсем...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int error()
{
    cout << "Error  ";
    return 0;
}

void f1(int a, int b, int c)
{
    if (cout << "1", a > b) throw error();
    if (cout << "2", b > c) throw error();
    if (cout << "3", a < c) throw error();
    cout << "All right 1   ";
}

void f2(int a, int b, int c)
{
    if ((cout << "1", a > b) || (cout << "2", b > c) || (cout << "3", a < c)) throw error();
    cout << "All right 2   ";
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    for(int a = 1; a <= 3; ++a)
    {
        for(int b = 1; b <= 3; ++b)
        {
            for(int c = 1; c <= 3; ++c)
            {
                cout << a << b << c << ":  ";
                try
                {
                    f1(a,b,c);
                }
                catch(...) {}
                try
                {
                    f2(a,b,c);
                }
                catch(...) {}
                cout << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Он выполняет один раз, а мне нужно что бы все выполнялось как отдельно)
или я что то пропустил где то

Comment: Типо по очереди

Comment: Будет выполняться все по очереди, пока не встретится код, который даст истину... Если первый же код должен сгенерировать исключение - понятно, что никакой последующий код уже больше выполняться не будет. У вас же в оригинале - исключение генерируется, если код дает условие true, так?

Comment: Мне надо как я написал выше без какой то истины или исключения.
просто избавится от повторения кода.

Comment: Так, как вы сформулировали - так я и ответил. Сформулируйте **корректно однозначно**, что вам нужно.

Comment: Господи, ну напишите макрос типа assert! - см. дополненный ответ. Только учтите, что в своих попытках сделать код понятнее вы его окончательно запутываете...

Comment: Обновил описания

Comment: С макросами немного не понял, типа внутри переменной будет код?

Comment: Если и это - дополнение к ответу - вас не убедит в том, что вы неправы, говоря, что проверяется **только** первое условие...

Comment: Это уже слишком сложно, зачем цикл использовать

Comment: Чтоб вы увидели **разные** варианты - когда проверяется одно условие, когда два, а когда и все три!

Comment: Я запутался если честно тоже), цикл не надо использовать, это только усложнит все.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете воспользоваться "проваливающимся" `switch-case`:

```
switch(код){
   case код_0:
   case код_1:
   case код_2:
   case код_3:
      throw WSAException();
      break;
}
```

Comment: Вы уверены, что "код" - это число, а не именно код? :)

Comment: switch точно не подойдет там именно код а не число :)

Comment: @Harry да, действительно. Сходу предположил, что код -- число